# How to optimise the following for loop code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, optimization

I have a very large dataset and I am using following code.
It's taking too much time for computation and I want to reduce number of iterations.

*How can I improve the code's performance?*

```py
import numpy as np

Z=np.asarray([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6],
              [7,8]])

R=np.asarray([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6]])

AL=np.asarray([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6]])

X=np.asarray([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9],
              [10,11,12]])

N = 4
M = 2
D = 3

result = np.ones([N, D])
for i in range(N):
  for l in range(D):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(M):
      temp.append(Z[i][j]*(R[j][l]+AL[j][l]*X[i][l]))
    result[i][l] = np.sum(temp)   

print(result)
```

Output is:

```
array([[ 18.,  36.,  60.],
       [ 95., 156., 231.],
       [232., 360., 510.],
       [429., 648., 897.]])
```

Comment: For starters, why is `temp` a list? It can simply be a float/int that keeps a running sum.

Comment: I think you can sum directly without building the temp list `result[i][l]=np.sum(Z[i][j]*(R[j][l]+AL[j][l]*X[i][l]) for j in range(M))`

Comment: thank you @Jean-François Fabre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `numpy`, prefer using matrix and array operations instead of `for` iterations. The performance is drastically better.

Your solution can be written as:

```py
result = Z.dot(R) + Z.dot(AL) * X
```

Output:

```
array([[ 18.,  36.,  60.],
       [ 95., 156., 231.],
       [232., 360., 510.],
       [429., 648., 897.]])
```