# How to optimize following code with minimum use of for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop, optimization, coding-efficiency

Code is taking too much time for computation and I want to reduce number of iterations. I tried to use method suggested by @Albuquerque [How to optimise the following for loop code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496917/how-to-optimise-the-following-for-loop-code), but for this code I have 3d array. Please suggest how to optimize following code.

```
K=2
D=3
N=3
sigma=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
F=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
X=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

W=
[
 [
  [1,2,3],
  [3,2,1]
 ],
 [
  [1,1,19],
  [1,2,1]
 ],
 [
  [2,2,2],
  [1,3,5]
 ]
]

result2= np.ones([N, D])
for i in range(N):
   for l in range(D):
     result2[i][l]=np.sum(W[i][k][l]*(F[k][l]+sigma[k][l]*X[i][l]) for k in range(K))


output-
array([[ 26.,  42.,  60.],
      [ 25.,  72., 441.],
      [ 48., 171., 360.]])
```

Comment: It would help if you explain what you are trying to do (with an input and output) and not just dump your code.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Right now it looks like some kind of product

Comment: thanks guys, I solved it. Using numpy einsum, we can perform multi-dimensional array operations. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) thanks again.